# PayPal charges card using bogus card details

Tags: paypal

Using the PayPal REST API, have the credit card form configured and processing correctly. Noticed that in sandbox mode the card validation is very loose, you can pretty much enter whatever you want for the payer details, as long as the card number is essentially valid.

I assume that once I change to live mode, using live credentials, the validation will be more strict.

*I run a test, using a valid card number, but intentionally use a bogus name, address, expiration date, and cvv (the cvv I provide is only 3 digits, it should be 4 for AMEX).*

**The payment is processed successfully!**

I scratch my head and make sure the site is really using the live credentials. It is. I check with my non sandbox PayPal account, it has actually received the payment.

What gives?

The amount was for $1. My assumption is that PayPal passed all the details along to AMEX (in this case) and AMEX saw that it was only $1, and didn't verify any other details? Fine, but wow, to me that's crazy! Talk about fraud waiting to happen.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Interesting... Unless someone knows what's going on, it'd be worth reporting this to PayPal

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your account is vetted when you first open it up, PayPal may or not may give you full access to fraud filters.  It sounds like you do have full access, which means it's going to accept payments even if AVS or CVV2 responses come back as a failure.

If you want to stop this, login to your PayPal account and go into your profile.  Look for Fraud Management Filters, Risk Controls, or something along those lines.  It's different depending on what version of PayPal account you have.

Once you're in those settings you should see lots of options for security filters you can set including AVS and CVV2 (card code).

Now, that would apply for the name, address, and cvv2, but it shouldn't apply for the expiration date.  Are you sure the test you ran included an invalid expiration date?  My guess is the card number and expiration were good, but you just used a bogus address and card code..??

Comment: Andrew, I just tested again, making sure the expiration date was also incorrect, it still goes through!


I haven't yet been able to confirm if your answer is correct in my case. I see the Risk Controls link, but when I click it I get a legal message about turning them on. Not sure if this means they are off? I'm the dev, so I need to ask someone else to enable in order to test. Will try to get that done.